# Inhemogenous and Homogeneous system of equations ex

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the dimension of the set of solutions in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of the following systems of equations. In each case, find the basis for the space of solutions of the corresponding homogeneous system, and one solution of the inhomogeneous system if it exists.
>
> $$x-y+z=1\\2x-3y+z=0\\x+y-z=5$$

On matrix form:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1\\2&-3&1\\1&1&-1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0\\0&-3&1\\2&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Using the formula $\text{row rank}+\dim \text{space of solutions}=n$, in which n is the number of variables.

I figured out that $\dim \text{space of solutions}=0$

Going back to solve the homogeneous equation we have:

$x+2y=0\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:y=0\\-3y+1z=0\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:z=0\\2x=0\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:x=0$

Solving now the inhomogeneous equation:

$x+2y=1\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:y=-\frac{3}{4}\\-3y+1z=0\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:z=-\frac{9}{4}\\2x=5\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:x=\frac{5}{2}$

I am sorry for the programming, those were supposed to be systems of equations.
Since I am self-studying and the book has no solutions, I would like someone to check if my answer is right.

**Questions:**

Is my answer right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiplying the first equation by $-2$ and adding to the secvond we get
$$-y-z=-2$$
multiplying the first equation by $-1$ and adding to the third we get
$$2y-2z=4$$
$$y-z=2$$
adding both equation we get
$$y=2$$ and $$z=0$$ therefore $x=3$